# Missing Right Click menu in Windows 7

Tags: delphi, windows-7, popup, right-click

We have a few different programs all compiled together in the same suite, recently we had a bug reported that `"The Right Click Shortcut Menu was missing."`
So as with any bug I tried to reproduce it and couldn't. No matter what I did the right click menu appeared on my system.

My first guess was that this was an OS issue. We know it works on Vista and XP, but on Windows 7 it doesn't. Unfortunately this issue only affects one of the programs in the suite and seemingly only on this one machine. AFAIK there isn't any code we've written to allow or prevent the default menu appearing so I'm not sure why it only affects one program.

The machine with the issue is a 32-bit machine running Windows 7. There was another issue to do with the regional settings (we have noticed backwards date formats even though the OS thinks it's UK it had been displaying MM/DD/YYYY format, but this was fixed when changing the regional settings to something else and back again). This did not resolve the issue.

Besides writing a new context pop-up, does anyone have any idea how I would even start to diagnose this issue?  Is there an API I can call to pop-up the default menu so I can monitor its behaviour? some windows message I can intercept the check its all running as it should be?

Comment: What is the right-click menu missing from?  An edit box?  A list box?  The entire app?

Comment: Which version of Delphi, there's was a problem with Delphi 2007 with the context menu.

Comment: It's Delphi 2007, and yes the entire app, TEdits, TcxEdits,TMemo, TComboBox....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Download [Delphi 2007 December updates](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/37483) to fix this problem
or andy [Context menu popup delay bug fix unit](http://cc.codegear.com/Item/25040)

Comment: Ah, we already have the unit (which is what is making the rest of suite work) but I wrote this one particular and wasn't aware of it. I just needed to include it in the DPR. Thanks